# C Complex looping issue

Tags: c

I am trying to right a small code that I would be able to process a speech. Now I have a small obstacle that I am facing. I have a counter `int i` and I have an array of 32 integers called `file`. What I want to do is when my counter `i` gets to 4 it should copy all the values from the `file` array into the `newarray`. This will continue tell the end of the `file` array. In the code below, I can pick the first 3 times then it just continues and does not stop when it is 4. I tried every way; however, I could not solve it.

```
int filesize = 34;
int newsize=4;

int file[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34}; 
int arraynew[newsize];

int begin =0;
int end = newsize;

int i=0;
int j=0;

while(begin < filesize){
  arraynew[begin] = file[begin];
  i++;
  printf(" I is:%d\n",i); 
  if(i== 4){
    i=0; 
    printf("Rest  I is:%d\n",i);         
    int start=0;
    int mid = (start + end)/2, m=0;
    for(;mid < end; mid++){
      arraynew[start+m] = arraynew[mid];
      m++;                      
    }  //shift array 2 places to the left and add 
       // another two value at the end then
       // pass to function.
  }
  begin++;                                
}
```

Result of the above code:

```
 I is:1
 I is:2
 I is:3
 I is:4
Rest  I is:0
 I is:1
 I is:2
 I is:3
 I is:4
Rest  I is:0
 I is:1
 I is:2
 I is:3
 I is:4
Rest  I is:0
 I is:14
 I is:15
 I is:16
 I is:17
 I is:18
 I is:19
 I is:20
 I is:21
 I is:22
 I is:23
 I is:24
 I is:25
 I is:26
 I is:27
 I is:28
 I is:29
 I is:30
 I is:31
 I is:32
 I is:33
 I is:34
```

Comment: Notice when i get to 14 i carries on with out rest. thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Using `begin` to index `arraynew` will access beyond the array's capacity.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Your input is an array with values 1..34 in array indexes 0..33.  What is the result you desire when your loop has finished?  Your explanation is not clear and your code doesn't bear much resemblance to what the explanation seems to want.

Comment: `arraynew[begin] = file[begin];` : Array out of range

Comment: Some code that you did not share is setting 'i' to 14.  The code above seems to work as you want.

Comment: i have copied the whole program. there is nothing is missing. @littleadv the problem is not in the length of what i am trying to read. it is in the logic. and to answer the question of the Welcome to stack Overflow: i need to process 4 integer at a time until i reach the end of the array, however the inner for loop should attempt to move the last two values in the newarray and then place the new 2 values in the place of the old. let say newarray is{1,2,3,4} the second iteration should be {3,4,5,6} and the third iteration is {5,6,7,8} and so forth.

Comment: BLUEPIXY: please look at the code carefully, there is nothing out of index here the sizes are fixed filesize=34; begin starts from 0 to the 34 as in the body of the while so where is the out of bond that you say. i suggest you run the code first. cause this is the whole program.

Comment: `arraynew[begin] = file[begin];` : So print `begin`. `arraynew` index range 0～3. Is `begin` 0～3? (it's 0～33)

Comment: i suggest "please look at the code carefully.".

Comment: Mate, ok lets ignore the arraynew[begin] = file[begin]; out of our why and focus on the index i. let say we are only traversing the file[begin] and when we have red 4 integers we should rest the i, Only rest the i. can you see the problem. it is nothing to do with the arraynew[begin] = file[begin];

Comment: It is believed to destroy the variable on the stack by writing data to the memory outside of the array.

Comment: in this case what do suggest to overcome this issue. do you think there is another why around it.

Comment: Memory is corrupt clearly. It is to write the correct code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose a code like the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print(int *array, int size){
    while(size--)
        printf("%d ", *array++);
    printf("\n");
}   

int main(){
    int file[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34}; 
    int filesize = sizeof(file)/sizeof(*file);
    int newsize=4;
    int arraynew[newsize];
    int i, m = newsize / 2;

    for(i=0; i + newsize -1 < filesize; i+= m){
        memcpy(arraynew, &file[i], sizeof(arraynew));
        print(arraynew, newsize);//print(&file[i], newsize);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: just one thing i fail to understand, is what difference does it make when i declare the length of the array as i did in my code arraysize=34 and the method you have used.( int filesize = sizeof(file)/sizeof(*file);). But again i can not thank you enough.

Comment: @user3448232 ; There is no difference between the `int filesize = 34;` and `int filesize = sizeof(file)/sizeof(*file);`. But former method is no direct relationship the size of array.